# Using field values in page.html.twig

Tags: entities, 8

Using Drupal 8.

I want to display the value of a field (field_date) at the top of my page, in the header, so I need to output it in page.html.twig. I'm having issue with this, though, which I think boil down to the scope of where variables are available.

To clarify - I can print field_date in node.html.twig no problem by just using content, but since I need it so high on the page, I'm hoping for a way to print it in page.html.twig.

I'm open to any solution, but here's a possible solution I picked up from searching on this same topic:

In THEMENAME.theme

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field().
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];

    if($element['#field_name'] == 'field_date') {
        $variables['promo_date'] = $element[0]['#markup'];
        dpm($variables['promo_date']);
    } 
}
```

In page.html.twig:

```
<div class="theme-date">{{ promo_date }}</div>
```

In this example, the dpm does work, but the promo_date displays nothing. Doing kint(node) returns a large number of methods, but none seem to be the fields I need.  Unfortunately the solution I borrowed from was taking a page-level variable and adding it to field.twig.html, and I think the scope reversal is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see the result of your code in `THEMENAME_preprocess_field()` you have to put `{{ promo_date }}` in a `field.html.twig`.

But in your question you asked about the `page.html.twig`. To access the field value in this template, you can use the node object, which is preloaded in the page template. But only if there is a node in the url of your page. Otherwise this will return an empty string:

```
{{ node.field_date.value }}
```

Comment: Does this mean I cannot use cleaner URLs, such as /page-name ?

Comment: That doesn't matter, the url can be an alias of the node too. But if you display a view, where nodes are inside, this will not work.

Comment: Okay, thank you. This is exactly what I needed. Previous attempts at using node I got bogged down in the structure/finding the value, but I gave up too soon.