# Theming custom fields

Tags: theming, entities, 8

Migrating from D7 to D8, can someone explain how to theme a custom field in a content type?

Say I start with the "Basic page" content type and I add an image field, however I don't want this image to appear in the body of the text, I want it to span the entire page.

In Drupal 7 I would have gone into /sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/page.tpl.php and added the following:

```
<?php if(isset($node->field_image_undernav) && count($node->field_image_undernav) > 0):?> 
    <?php $imagePath = file_create_url($node->field_image_undernav['und'][0]['uri']); ?>
    <img class="img-responsive" id="img-top" src="<?php print $imagePath;?>"/>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How do I do this in Drupal 8? I'm guessing it's something like /themes/mytheme/page.html.twig and adding:

```
{# Top Image #}
    {% if page.machine_name_of_field %}
       {% block machine_name_of_field %}
         {{ page.machine_name_of_field }}
    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

This changes where I can render the image in the template, but includes unwanted fields (like title) and some DIV wrappers. I just want to locate the image URL.

If I do

```
{{ dump(page.machine_machine_name_of_field) }}
```

I get NULL. If I dump(page), I see the URL but concatenated as part of a string in ["#markup"]. Any way to extract just the image URL from this field so I can place it exactly where and how I want?

The [official D8 theming documentation](https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8) doesn't seem to have this info, and unofficial guides like [John Hannah's](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-8-theming-fundamentals-part-1) is helpful but seems to stop after basic setup.

Any guidance on this specific issue or documentation to learn more is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems you're asking the very same thing as http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190350/using-field-values-in-page-html-twig, which was posted just a short while ago?

Comment: Similar goals but I did a dump node as well, it doesn't have the values I want: 

    'object(Drupal\node\Entity\Node)#331 (24) { ["in_preview"]=> NULL ["values":protected]=> array(20) { ["vid"]=> array(1) { ["x-default"]=> string(1) "2" } ["langcode"]=> array(1) { ["x-default"]=> string(2) "en" } ["revision_timestamp"]=> array(1) { ["x-default"]=> string(10) "1454210500" } ["revision_uid"]=> array(1) { ["x-default"]=> string(1) "1" } ["revision_log"]=> array(1) { ["x-default"]=> NULL } ["nid"]=> array(1) { ["x-default"]=> string(1) "2" } ["type"]=> array(1) { ["x-default"]=> string(4) ...'

Comment: Yes it does. Just do what the other answer suggested. Don't use dump() with entities, it doesn't work for complex structures. If anything, then use dump(node.toArray()). See also wizzlern.nl/drupal/drupal-8-entity-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Berdir](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/31/berdir) set me in the right direction with [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190350/using-field-values-in-page-html-twig) but the actual specifics of what I needed are buried in the replies to [this question on rendering images from a node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179426/render-image-field-from-node-in-page-html-twig):

in  /themes/mytheme/page.html.twig add

`{{ file_url(node.machine_name_of_field.entity.uri.value) }}`

That renders just the image URL so I can place the image anywhere.